# Windows Form application set as MdiContainer, child forms change display on load

Tags: vb.net, mdiparent

I have a basic Windows Form application, written in VB.

Main Form is set to `IsMdiContainer = true`.

I have a simple childForm setup to the correct size to fill the space.
I create a global variable of it.

```
Public childForm as childFormClass = new childFormClass
```

I set `childForm.MdiParent = Me`   (i.e. MainForm)

When I call `childForm.Show()` the various controls are not in there designed locations, and some even gone? (assume off the side). Things seem to move to the right.

I have been chasing this issue for a while and cannot find a solution. Any advice welcomed.

Cheers,
Graeme

[image: Child Form design]

[image: Running app showing moved and missing controls]

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing screenshots of the important views might not be a bad idea either.

Comment: Good idea, images added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
On the child form, I had to set `AutoScalMode = Inherit`

It was still on the default of `AutoScalMode = font`